# PySpark - Replace Null values with the mean of corresponding row

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, fillna

I have the following pyspark dataframe :

```
df
col1 col2 col3
1      2    3
4    None   6
7      8   None
```

I want to replace None (or Null) values by the mean of the row they are into.
the output would look like :

```
df_result
col1 col2 col3
1      2    3
4      5    6
7      8   7.5
```

Everything I tried leads to the error 'Column is not iterable' or 'Invalid argument, not a string or column'.
Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Careful with performance while using `mapinPandas` function..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Using only spark-in built functions:`**

Try with **`Higher order array (aggregate)`** functions and count the number of **`non null elements(using lambda functions)`** in the array.

Then calculate the `mean of the elements`.

Finally `divide` and **`replace the nulls(case + when statement)`** with mean value.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,False)
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|1   |2   |3   |
#|4   |null|6   |
#|7   |8   |null|
#+----+----+----+

#add nulls_count filed to check how many null values are there in all the columns
#cast all columns as an array
#sum_elems as sum of all elements of array
#calculate the mean based on non null values
df1 = df.withColumn("nulls_count",size(filter(array(*[isnull(col(c)) for c in df.columns]), lambda x: x))).\
  withColumn("arr_vals",array(*[coalesce(col(c),lit(0)) for c in df.columns])).\
  withColumn("sum_elems",expr("aggregate(arr_vals,cast(0 as bigint),(acc, x) -> acc + x)")).\
  withColumn("mean_val",expr('round(sum_elems/((size(arr_vals))-nulls_count),1)'))

df1.select([when(col(c).isNull(), col("mean_val")).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show(10,False)
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|1.0 |2.0 |3.0 |
#|4.0 |5.0 |6.0 |
#|7.0 |8.0 |7.5 |
#+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Easy solution with `mapinPandas`

```
def fillna(iterator):
    for df in iterator:
        yield df.mask(df.isna(), df.mean(1), axis=0)

result = df.mapInPandas(fillna, ','.join(map('{} float'.format, df.columns)))
```

Result

```
result.show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
| 1.0| 2.0| 3.0|
| 4.0| 5.0| 6.0|
| 7.0| 8.0| 7.5|
+----+----+----+
```